# How do I get the Telerik AutoComplete Box working using Razor Syntax in my ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

I am trying to get data from a specific column in a database table to populate the Telerik AutoComplete box using the Razor Template syntax in ASP.NET MVC3. Here is my html code:

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
@model IEnumerable<COOLTool.Models.Agency>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2 id="searchHeading2">Search</h2>
<br/>
@(Html.Telerik().AutoComplete()
   .BindTo(IEnumerable < COOLTool.Models.Agency > ViewData["CA_AgencyName"])
   .Render();       

)
```

Here is my C# class:

```
namespace COOLTool.Models
```

{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public partial class Agency
{
    public int CA_AgencyID { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyName { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyAcronym { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyAcronym_SOLID { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyHomePageURL { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyContact { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyCredentialType { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyStreetAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyStreetAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyCity { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyState { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyZip { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyCountry { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyPhonePrimary { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CA_AgencyPhonePrimaryExtension { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyPhoneSecondary { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyFax { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CA_AgencyRecordAddedDate { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyRecordAddedUserID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CA_AgencyRecordUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CA_AgencyRecordUpdatedUserID { get; set; }
    public int CA_AgencyStatus { get; set; }
    public bool CA_Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is exactly, but from the look of things you're most likely running into issued due to multiple reasons.

First of all, it should be noted that the AutoComplete component needs to be bound to an `IEnumerable<string>`, and not an `IEnumerable` of your custom object, as described in [this documentation article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-data-binding-server-binding.html). This would mean that this: `.BindTo(IEnumerable < COOLTool.Models.Agency > ViewData["CA_AgencyName"])` has to be changed to this: `.BindTo(IEnumerable < string > ViewData["CA_AgencyName"])`.

Now, what you need to do is ensure that you are actually saving something in your ViewData under the key "CA_AgencyName". If you are not then this would again explain why you are running into issues. As an example I have the following ActionResult for a View called "Index":

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Agency> myList = new List<Agency>();
    myList.Add(new Agency() { CA_AgencyName = "Name 1" });
    myList.Add(new Agency() { CA_AgencyName = "Name 2" });
    myList.Add(new Agency() { CA_AgencyName = "Different" });

    List<String> listToBind = new List<String>();

    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        listToBind.Add(item.CA_AgencyName);
    }

    ViewData["CA_AgencyName"] = listToBind;

    return View();
}
```

This is just dummy data of course, but it gives you the general idea. Now in my View I have just done the following:

```
@(Html.Telerik().AutoComplete().Name("Test").BindTo((IEnumerable<String>)ViewData["CA_AgencyName"]))
```

Note that since I am using `@(...)` I do not explicitly call `.Render();` as this should only be used when using `@{...}`.

All of the above gives you a working Telerik AutoComplete component on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you the code of http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete "Jquery autocomplete "
working code . If you need it reply me

Answer (score 0):

This is the Jquery Method which will call the controller.It will take first three char of the search and send it to the parameter to controller.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#AutoComplete").keypress(function () {
                var title = $("#AutoComplete").val();
                var availableTags = [];
                if (title.length == 3) {
                    $.get("/Wk/GetTitle/" + title, function (data) {
                        var arr = jQuery.makeArray(data.split(','));
                        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                            availableTags.push(arr[i]);
                        }
                        $("#AutoComplete").autocomplete({
                            source: availableTags
                        });
//                        $("#AutoComplete").select();
                    });

                }
            });
        });
```

Then This is the controller code .

```
 [HttpGet]
    public StringBuilder GetTitle(string inputString)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<string> title = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        string slug = RouteData.Values.Values.ElementAt(2).ToString();
        title = pageBL.GetTitleAutocomplete(slug);

        for (i = 0; i <= title.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i != title.Count -1 )
                sb = sb.Append(title.ElementAt(i) + ",");
            else
                sb = sb.Append(title.ElementAt(i) );
        }
        return sb;
    }
```

This controller take the parameter and return the desired output in the string builder .
The format is For Ex:India,Indiana,Indonesia ...
The Jquery take the op and show in the search Box
Here #Autocomplete is the text box where the search is done.

Tell Me if you get any problem